# NTFS - Why is the partition size limited to 16 TB with 4K Cluster?

Tags: ntfs

How do you calculate the max. size of 16 TB with a the number 4K? Is it because 2^32)-1)*4K byte is about 16 terabyte?

4K = 4000

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/ntfs-overview#support-for-large-volumes

Comment: You link to an autorative source that answers this question?

Comment: i have a little problem earning points to write freely on stackexchange. someone blocked me on one of the many stackexchange sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the fact that [NTFS supports 2^32 - 1 clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/ntfs-overview):

> NTFS can support volumes as large as 8 petabytes on Windows Server 2019 and newer and Windows 10, version 1709 and newer (older versions support up to 256 TB). Supported volume sizes are affected by the cluster size and the number of clusters. With (2^32 – 1) clusters (the maximum number of clusters that NTFS supports), the following volume and file sizes are supported.

In short, 2^32 * 4kB = 16TB.

Comment: thank you for your info